# WCF Async Method Not Always Invoked

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I have three identical WCF self-hosted Net.Tcp services listening on three separate machines. From my client, I create a task for each server which containts an instance of my WCF client (one for each server), ultimately invoking one of the WCF operations on each service asynchronously.

What I'm noticing is that the service call is unreliable. That is, in some cases, the calls work, in others they don't. Each run fails on a different one of the three machines, but always only one of the three, never two or all three.

I have verbose WCF tracing enabled on all servers and my client. For the server that fails, there is no evidence on the server side that a connection is ever established. On the client side, the service trace log doesn't even indicate that a connection attempt was made. My console debug logs show the code is indeed being hit though.

Here is my async method being invoked:

```
public async Task InstallAsync(string installerPath, string commandLine)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("[{0}] InstallerAgentServiceClient.InstallAsync({1}, {2})", _endpointAddress,
        installerPath, commandLine);

    try
    {
        _proxy = new InstallerAgentService.InstallerAgentServiceClient(
            new InstanceContext(this), // assign callback class instance
            new NetTcpBinding(),
            _endpointAddress);

        _proxy.InnerChannel.Faulted +=
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Inner channel faulted for {0}!", _endpointAddress));
            };

        _proxy.InnerChannel.Closed +=
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Inner channel closed for {0}!", _endpointAddress));
            };

        await _proxy.InstallAsync(installerPath, commandLine);  // <=== *Sometimes* this doesn't work, and never throws an exception
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
        Logger.ErrorException(ce.Message, ce);
        _proxy.Abort();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException te)
    {
        Logger.ErrorException(te.Message, te);
        _proxy.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.ErrorException(e.Message, e);
        _proxy.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Client app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    ...
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
              switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="c:\logs\Cmc.Installer.App.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="logListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\logs\Cmc.Installer.App.log.txt" />
        <add name="consoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging maxMessagesToLog="30000"
                      logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                      logKnownPii="true">
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IInstallerAgentService"
                 openTimeout="00:00:30"
                 sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                 closeTimeout="00:00:30"
                 receiveTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807">
        </binding>  
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address=""
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IInstallerAgentService"
        contract="InstallerAgentService.IInstallerAgentService" name="NetTcpBinding_IInstallerAgentService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="c2kbuild@mydomain.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Service app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MsiLog" value="C:\logs\Cmc.Installer.Agent.MSI.log.txt" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
              switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="c:\logs\Cmc.Installer.Agent.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="logListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\logs\Cmc.Installer.Agent.Console.log.txt" />
        <add name="consoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging maxMessagesToLog="30000"
                      logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:00:30"
                 sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                 closeTimeout="00:00:30"
                 receiveTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807">
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="Cmc.Installer.Agent.InstallerAgentService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingNamespace="http://mydomain.com/installer/2014/05"
                  contract="Cmc.Installer.Agent.IInstallerAgentService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://*:8890" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://*:8889" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does it throw an exception? do you have the exception?

Comment: It never throws an exception.

Comment: Is there a chance you do not `await` the result of `InstallAsync` somewhere you're calling it? Also, put `Debug.WriteLine(new { SynchronizationContext.Current })` before `await`, what does it show? Besides, put a `Debug.Assert(false)` right after `await`, does it get hit?

Comment: The first debug shows several `{ Current =  }` and the assert(false) gets hit after the `await`.

Comment: What's interesting here is that my first and only web service call has been `InstallAsync()`. If I add a `Heartbeat()` synchronous call right after each construction of the client proxy, all instances call the `InstallAsync()` method just fine. I wonder if there is a bug or poorly documented caveat with async WCF where one must make a synchronous call before any others.